# use Highcharts Api to show multiples values

Tags: highcharts

Hi everyone I am new using highcharts, I have my data structure and when I try to show, I don't see anything

```
  function nueva (current_data){
    var seriesOptions = [],
    seriesCounter = 0,
    type = ['jobs_running', 'jobs_pending'];
    function createChart() {
      $('#containerChart').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
          valueDecimals: 2
        },
          series: seriesOptions
        });
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < current_data['names'].length; j++){
      var all_element = []
      name_project = current_data['names'][j];
      for (var i = 0; i < type.length; i++){
        seriesCounter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < type.length; i++){
          seriesOptions[j] = {
              name: type[i],
              data: current_data[name_project][type[i]],
          };
        }
      }
      createChart();
    }
  }
```

I pass `current_data` to my function that is like this

[image]

I want to show 'jobs_running' and 'jobs_pendding' I set the value to `seriesOptions`

[image]

and my array of data has this

[image]

Any idea why I don't see anything in the chart! I am missing something.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console? Could you post live example of your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you can find your answer in this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ekekp8rh/1/

Not sure what you were hoping to get but at least this displays a chart.

```
var data = {
projects: [{
    name: 'Project X',
    jobs_running: [
      [1459814400000, 121],
      [1459900800000, 205],
      [1459987200000, 155],
      [1460073600000, 458]
    ],
    jobs_pending: [
      [1459814400000, 146],
      [1459900800000, 149],
      [1459987200000, 158],
      [1460073600000, 184]
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'Project Y',
    jobs_running: [
      [1459814400000, 221],
      [1459900800000, 295],
      [1459987200000, 255],
      [1460073600000, 258]
    ],
    jobs_pending: [
      [1459814400000, 246],
      [1459900800000, 249],
      [1459987200000, 258],
      [1460073600000, 284]
    ]
  }]
};
nueva(data);

function nueva(current_data) {
  var seriesOptions = [],
    type = ['jobs_running', 'jobs_pending'];
  for (var j = 0; j < current_data['projects'].length; j++) {
    var project = current_data['projects'][j];
    for (var i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {
      seriesOptions.push({
        name: project.name + ' ' + type[i],
        data: project[type[i]]
      });
    }
  }
  $('#containerChart').highcharts('StockChart', {
    series: seriesOptions
  });
}
```